# Count mismatch on sql query execution from JPA

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I have written a Union all sql query.My DB is Oracle. I have included it as a native query in JPA. When I execute the query on DB the count shows 28,131,56 rows but on JPA side executed sends only 51,299 rows.

query is

```
 with p as(select * from table1), b as (select * from table2) select * from(select * from p union all 
 select * from b);
```

I have not set any offset/ done any chunking but still not getting the exact count. How can I get the entire data

Thanks

Comment: Why is your query not `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2`? Why complicate it with a subquery factoring clause and a nested query when they aren't necessary?

Comment: I have 10 different tables where union all is applied. I saw some delay in the response when union all added in between the queries